# Is there any relation between advertising interval, walking speed, and window size of moving average filter?

Tags: ibeacon, moving-average, estimote, indoor-positioning-system

My beacons have advertisement interval of 330ms. I use an iOS device to scan the advertisement packet whose scanning rate is 1 scan per second on average. I want to use the moving average filter to smooth the fluctuating RSSI values. Considering the walking speed of 1.2 m/s and the advertisement interval of 330 ms, what should be the size of a window in the moving average filter? Is there any mathematical relationship between them?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no one correct answer here.  It is a trade-off between noise in the distance estimate and lag time.

The large (and longer) your statistical sample, the more lag time there will be in a running average.  A 20 second window will tell you where you were on average over the last 20 seconds, and filter out a lot of noise.  A 5 second running average will tell you where you were on average over the last 5 seconds, but with much more noise on the calculation.

How much lag you can tolerate and how much noise you can tolerate all depend on your use case.  Use cases that are very time sensitive may sacrifice accuracy for the sake of less lag.  Conversely use cases needing greater accuracy may accept more lag to filter out more noise on the estimate.

Comment: Indeed, it's a trade-off between noise in the RSS/distance estimate and the lag time. However, considering the walking speed (speed of tag device), can we relate it to the size of the window? For eg. at walking speed of 1.2 m/s and the advertisement interval of 330 ms (3 packets per second), which window size would be best, 4 or 5 (principally)? Can we define it with any principle? Though window size 5 gives smoother data with less standard deviation, I want to explain the selection of window size with any principle. Thank you.